# Font-awesome Fonts inconsistent rendering

Tags: ios, ipad, google-chrome, font-awesome

I am currently developing a mobile site, however, I've met some problems with Font Awesome. Firstly, there's inconsistent rendering of the fonts with Chrome. Sometimes, randomly, the fonts will appear as blank squares, but when I mouse over them, the original icon will display again. Also, when using IPad version of the safari mobile, the fonts appear as blank squares instead of proper fonts. I tried using other mobile browsers like android's and iphone's, but I cannot reproduce the same problem as with the IPad's. Anyone meet with this same problem and have a solution? Please help! I looked through the all the similar questions but it doesn't solve the problem I'm facing... I'm using Font Awesome 4.0.3 by the way...

Answer (score 1):

It's currently an open bug in Chrome. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336075), [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336170) and [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2763).

Comment: oh, so it's not a problem with my website, but with chrome then? thank you so much for letting me know. :) but any help with the mobile safari problem?

Comment: what problem with mobile safari?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is some problem caused in the new chrome for all fonts and not just font-awesome. For me, not just the icon fonts appears so, event the text font (proxima nova) appears all broken after some time but gets corrected as soon as I hover over it or select the text. I previously noticed this problem in the beta build of the chrome and have been facing this problem in the stable build ever since chrome was updated (3 days ago). Maybe look out for a fix from Google soon!

Comment: oh is that so? thanks for your reply :) but any way to solve the IPad safari mobile problem?